# Можно ли сделать ключ PRIMARY KEY с определенного числа?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Только начал учить sqlite3, появился вопрос. У меня есть таблица users, у каждого есть ключ id его я записал как PRIMARY KEY. Тут вопрос, можно ли сделать, чтобы этот ключ начинался не с числа один, а к примеру с числа 5?

Comment: У вас колонка id какого типа ? Если номер обычный - то можно самому сделать нумерацию, если автономератор - нельзя. В случае обычного номера типа число вам придётся каждый раз самостоятельно программировать следующий номер. Т.е. писать запрос, искать максимум, затем прибавлять к максимуму одну единицу и сохранять в таблицу users. В случае автонумератора, это ничего делать не надо, но тогда автонумератор будет сам нумеровать, без вас, начиная с числа 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/692856/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov согласен, я был не прав )